# PostgreSQL join with 2 mysql tables by foreign data wrapper

Tags: mysql, postgresql, foreign-data-wrapper

I have 4 servers 2 are postgres and 2 others are MySql, had trouble with mysql_fdw , tried to join my postgres table with foreign postgres then mysql's one - everything is fine, query's execution time is near 0.05s - So everything is good.

Right after that , I've added JOIN to another one mysql table on other Mysql Server through another mysql_fwd server, and this time execution time became about 150-200s, that's not acceptable. Does anyone find a solution for that or maybe some tricks.
Thanks!

Comment: what does an explain show? Where is the delay happening.

Comment: A much more detailed description of what happens where, when is needed. Which servers connect to which others? Show `explain analyze` output. Show the query. Imagine you're talking to someone who doesn't know your setup (because, well, we don't) and describe it to them.